# How to invoke default deserialize with gson

Tags: java, android, gson, json

I get a json that has "field" field. 
If the "field" has data, then there is an OBJECT that has many (about 20) other fields that are also objects. I can deserialize them without any problems. 
But if "field" has no data, it is an empty ARRAY (I know it's crazy, but that's the response from server and I can't change it). 
Something like this:

When empty:

```
"extras":[

]
```

Has some data:

```
"extras": {
    "22":{ "name":"some name" },
    "59":{ "name":"some other name" },
    and so on...
}
```

So, when there if no data (empty array), I obviously get the exception

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 4319
```

I tried to use custom JavaDeserializer:

```
public class ExtrasAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Extras> {
    @Override
    public Extras deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOf,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            // deserialize normally

            // the following does not work, as it makes recursive calls
            // to the same function
            //return context.deserialize(jsonObject,
            //                       new TypeToken<Object>(){}.getType());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I read the json the following way

```
Gson gsonDecoder = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Extras.class, new ExtrasAdapter();
// httpResponse contains json with extras filed. 
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
Extras response = gsonDecoder.fromJson(reader, Extras.class);
```

I don't want to deserialize all 20 fields manually (I know this is an option), I just want to call context.defaultDeserialize(), or something like that. 
Once again: I don't have any problems deserializing normal json, creating custom objects, registering custom TypeAdapters, custom JavaDeserializers. It all works already. I need only  some solution for handling a data, that can be both ARRAY and OBJECT. 
 
Thanks for any help.

======================
The Joey's answer works perfect. That right the thing I was looking for. 
I'll post my code here.

```
public class SafeTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                try {
                    delegate.write(out, value);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    delegate.write(out, null);
                }
            }
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                try {
                    return delegate.read(in);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w("Adapter Factory", "IOException. Value skipped");
                    in.skipValue();
                    return null;
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.w("Adapter Factory", "IllegalStateException. Value skipped");
                    in.skipValue();
                    return null;
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    Log.w("Adapter Factory", "JsonSyntaxException. Value skipped");
                    in.skipValue();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: paste that code in which you are deserializing data when array is available

Comment: Array cannot be available. It only can be empty. If I would need to deserialize array, I would do it in the catch block.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using GSON >= 2.2.1 and look for the [TypeAdapterFactory](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) class.

This will give you the ability to inspect the Object before you deserialize it and apply custom code while avoiding recursions.

Here is an example of the [getDelegateAdapter](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getDelegateAdapter-com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory-com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken-) you can use.

Comment: +1 for getDelegateAdapter() This the good solution for implementing a common functionality irrespective of the Type of object. For instance, calling a post-deserialization function on the object.

Answer (score 12):

```
public class ExtrasAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Extras> {
@Override
public Extras deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOf, 
              JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    try {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject , Extras.class); // default deserialization

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach avoids infinite recursion because you're using a new Gson object that doesn't have the adapter registered. In that case, you could just as well call deserialize on it.

Comment: So simple. Brilliant.

Comment: The problem with this is that usually you will have other special rules and adapters you want on your Gson instance. This creates a new default one without your app specific rules

Comment: Still `StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming in late, you don't need to implement a TypeAdapter to solve this problem, although doing so is a perfectly valid solution.

The answer to this problem is actually in the original question:

```
public class ExtrasAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Extras> {

@Override
public Extras deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOf, 
          JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    try {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        // deserialize normally

        // the following does not work, as it makes recursive calls 
        // to the same function 
        //return context.deserialize(jsonObject, new TypeToken<Object>(){}.getType());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The commented out

```
return context.deserialize(jsonObject, new TypeToken<Object>(){}.getType());
```

is almost the solution. The issue is two fold. First, jsonObject is the exact object passed into this function originally.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
```

So passing it into context.deserialize() will create recursion, and eventually OOM. The solution here is to parse out the objects inside of jsonObject.

This leads us to the second problem, which is that there are two things getting mixed here. "Extras" is an object type, presumably with a concrete class backing it (and possibly an empty array). "Extra" is a map. Attempting to parse an "Extra" as an "Extras" isn't going to work. To that end, I would suggest the following definition of "Extras":

```
public class Extras {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> extras;
    // you could also create a concrete class for "Extra"
    //and have this be a Map<String, Extra>
}
```

In which case the problem becomes trivial for solving with context.deserialize.

As I stated above, a TypeAdatper is a perfectly valid solution for this problem. I just believe that it's more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

I created an alternative TypeAdapter based on my needs to let empty arrays deserialize to null, but only for the classes I specify:

```
class EmptyArraysAsNullTypeAdapterFactory @Inject constructor() : TypeAdapterFactory {

companion object {

    // Add classes here as needed
    private val classesAllowedEmptyArrayAsNull = arrayOf(Location::class.java,
                                                         Results::class.java)

    private fun isAllowedClass(rawType: Class<*>): Boolean {
        return classesAllowedEmptyArrayAsNull.find { rawType.isAssignableFrom(it) } != null
    }
}

override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
    val delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type)

    val rawType = type.rawType as Class<T>

    return object : TypeAdapter<T>() {

        override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: T?) {
            delegate.write(out, value)
        }

        override fun read(reader: JsonReader): T? {
            return if (reader.peek() === JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY && isAllowedClass(rawType)) {
                reader.beginArray()

                // If the array is empty, assume it is signifying null
                if (!reader.hasNext()) {
                    reader.endArray()
                    null
                } else {
                    throw JsonParseException("Not expecting a non-empty array when deserializing: ${type.rawType.name}")
                }

            } else {
                delegate.read(reader)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}